# Spring Boot Get Request with JSON

Tags: java, web-services, spring-boot

Trying to do the following.  I have an endpoint:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/getInfo", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<Object> getInfo(@RequestBody Map<String, String> payload) {
  String name = payload.get("name");
  System.out.println(name);
  return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

However when I do a call to it (via TestRestTemplate):

```
String url = "http://localhost:8090/api/getInfo?{\"name\":\"myName\"}";
```

I am getting an error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not enough variable values available to expand '"name"'
```

Do the get endpoints not allow for JSON to go to them?

Comment: The duplicate explains what's going on within the `RestTemplate`, but that's a weird URL. How do you expect to retrieve the `{\"name\":\"myName\"}` part?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis This is the string version of what of the consumers produces in an ajax request.  I think this might need to be done in a post.

Comment: Then it should be in the body of the request, and that request should be a POST (since HTTP servers aren't required to look at the body of a GET request).